# Java: How can I get rid of a specific JPanel by clicking an arrow key?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, key-bindings, keylistener

This is my inner class that creates the graphic text. I want to be able to press an arrow key and have it disappear. I'm sure it involves the remove method somehow, but I'm in over my head. Very new at this.

```
// STARTUP TEXT

class TextPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public TextPanel(){
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    // PAINT METHOD
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g2){
        super.paintComponent(g2);
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        g2.drawString("Press an arrow key to start", this.getWidth()/4, this.getHeight()/2);
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK You have to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to respond to arrow key then to remove panel (I think from frame) use either `setVisible(false)` of panel or `remove(component)` method of frame.

Comment: I figured that, but how would I do that?

Comment: @Jazzertron read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Comment: @HarryJoy : Wish I could start a new Thread for this. But please tell me, what does the Abbreviation AFAIK stands for ? +1 for the KeyBinding stuff though.  :-) Regards

Comment: @GagandeepBali : AFAIK = *As Far As I Know.* ;p

Comment: @HarryJoy : AFAIK, I never thought it's that easy :-) Thankyou.

Comment: @GagandeepBali google is your friend as well: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=afaik

Comment: @kleopatra : AFAIK, I completely forgot that thing also :-) LOL Regards

Answer (score 2):

```
/** Handle the key typed event  */
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    /** Handle the key-pressed event  */
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    /** Handle the key-released event  */
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key=e.getKeyCode();
        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {

            this.setVisible(false);

        }
        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {

            this.setVisible(true);

        }

    }
```

Comment: +1, though normally with Swing we don't use KeyEvent, they are meant to be used with AWT, but since it's a valuable information you had given, that's why :-)  Regards